# draw game on lichess after 2 repetitions?

Tags: draw

I was playing this game with white

https://lichess.org/INsUhHEO

I was losing, so I was happy to see the 3-position draw button appearing, which I clicked.

But after, reviewing the game, I couldn't see a reason for that to happen, I see only 2 repetition...

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same position appeared after 56. Kf8, 58. Kf8 and 60. Kf8 -- 3 repetitions of the position (not moves).

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found it sorry, the third one was the NEXT move, the button appears just before (make sense)

sorry for the stupid question :)

good night

Comment: A draw can be claimed when the third repetition is about to occur.

Comment: @PhishMaster Not on lichess and other online sites -- the draw is claimable online only when the third repetition is on the board.